# Setting a border around Report detail in Access 2010 that automatically is sized to fit

Tags: ms-access

Could anyone please provide me with the full VBA code that would set a (thin) border around the detail in my Reports that are automatically sized to fit each one? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question... I would search this direction:

- manually create Line1 at top of detail section
- manually create Line2 at bottom of detail section

Use the information [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/830313-vertical-line-between-snaking-columns-ms-access-reports) to print 2 vertical lines using the Print event. You should be able to use Line1 and Line2 .Top property to easily calculate the height of the vertical line.